# Create variable to be set in deployment

Tags: jekyll

How do I set a variable in jekyll for a link that will be determined by the environment that it's deployed in?

i.e.

If I deploy in sandbox I want `{{site.REDIRECT_LINK}}` to be set to a different URL than when it's deployed in production.

I'm assuming I set it in the `_config` file, but is there anything I need to set up for docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set variables in your config file that match your environment names:

```yaml
staging:
  redirect_link: http://staging.example.com
production:
  redirect_link: http://example.com
```

Then you can call `{{ site[jekyll.environment].redirect_link }}`. If you are building in your staging environment you will get "http://staging.example.com"